# Eclipse Dali can not find table relations for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, jpa, dali

I am using eclipse dali to generate jpa entities .. It works fine for Oracle, but for MS SQL Server , Dali can not find relations between tables, therefore the generated entities do not have any relations to each other. Has anybody come accross this problem?.

EDIT :

I have opened a bug for this problem. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334250
It looks like the problem is related to eclipse data tools. I have opened a new bug ; https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the problem is related to jdbc drivers that are jdbc 4.0 compliant. As a workaround, you can use [jtds driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) which is jdbc 3.0 compliant.